# Is there a way to read Wordpress export file in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wordpress, ruby-on-rails-4

Im planning to migrate all my Wordpress posts to a Rails app that Im going to create. So I want to know how to read the Wordpress export file in Rails and get those data.

Comment: Wordpress doesn't have an export function does it?  What format does it export in?

Comment: @japed Wordpress have an inbuilt export function and exports into an XML file

Comment: in which case you'll want to look into [nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) or [simple xml](https://github.com/maik/xml-simple) to parse the data

Comment: Take a look at my answer. Parsing will not be easy, and there is a good part of the work that as already be done (the format is not exactly pretty).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly what you are looking for, but have a look at the [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/) importer. Jekyll is a blogging platform coded in Ruby, and it has an [importers](http://import.jekyllrb.com/docs/wordpress/) that are able to decipher the wordpress format.

You could either try it, and see what you get as an output, or look at the code to modify it the way you need. You can look at the code [here](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-import/blob/master/lib/jekyll-import/importers/wordpress.rb).